# ¿Cómo definir la altura de elementos?

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Me sucede esto:

[image: me pasa esto]

Necesito hacer esta distribución con Bootstrap y la altura de los banner de la derecha se me desordena cuando cambio de pantalla. Mi problema es que el alto de las 2 filas de la derecha se me desordenan.

¿Cómo arreglo eso?

El código es el siguiente (presionar botón de "Página completa" para ver el problema):

```css
.primer_banner {
  background: #eee;
}

.segundo_banner {
  background: #bdf
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="first-section">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Carrousel -->

    <!--<div class="col-md-12">-->
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>

          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="https://placehold.it/800x400/a00" class="img-responsive" alt="paisaje1">
              <div class="carousel-caption">

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="https://placehold.it/800x400/0a0" class="img-responsive" alt="paisaje2">
              <div class="carousel-caption">

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="https://placehold.it/800x400/00a" class="img-responsive" alt="paisaje3">
              <div class="carousel-caption">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5" id="banner_derecha">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="primer_banner col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <h4>banner1</h4>
          <h6>Realizalos de manera mas simple</h6>
          <!--enlace-->
          <a href="">AQUI</a>

        </div>
        <div class="segundo_banner col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <h4>banner2<br> igualar alto</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--  </div>-->
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hola Karla , bienvenida a SOes , sería genial que compartieras el código que produce  la imagen para saber como y en que parte del código ayudar.

Comment: Depende de que versión de Bootstrap uses. Si estás con la 3.X o inferior, bootstrap usa floats, por lo que no puedes tener una altura igual (a menos que uses javascript). En cambio, Bootstrap 4.0 usa flexbox, una propiedad en alza que hace que los divs que antes eran floats, sean ahora flex y ocupen el mismo espacio vertical que el contenido más alto.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Karla!, es importante realizar los consejos de los demás usuarios. Es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio (y obtendrás tu primera medalla). Además es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te da brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías cambiar los estilos de los contenedores para utilizar [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox), de ese modo harías que el contenedor del carrusel tenga un `display: flex` permitiendo que `#banner_derecha` ocupe el 100% del alto. A partir de ahí, podrías volver a usar `flex` (con `flex:1`) para el `.row` y los banners de la derecha o, como ya hay un alto definido, simplemente especificar un alto del 50% para cada uno de ellos.

Aquí puedes ver esta opción funcionando:

```css
section.first-section {
  display: flex;
}

#banner_derecha {
  height: 100%;
}

#banner_derecha > .row {
  height: 100%;
}

.primer_banner {
  background: #eee;
  height:50%;
}

.segundo_banner {
  background: #bdf;
  height:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="first-section">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Carrousel -->

    <!--<div class="col-md-12">-->
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>

          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="https://placehold.it/800x400/a00" class="img-responsive" alt="paisaje1">
              <div class="carousel-caption">

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="https://placehold.it/800x400/0a0" class="img-responsive" alt="paisaje2">
              <div class="carousel-caption">

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="https://placehold.it/800x400/00a" class="img-responsive" alt="paisaje3">
              <div class="carousel-caption">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5" id="banner_derecha">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="primer_banner col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <h4>banner1</h4>
          <h6>Realizalos de manera mas simple</h6>
          <!--enlace-->
          <a href="">AQUI</a>

        </div>
        <div class="segundo_banner col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <h4>banner2<br> igualar alto</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--  </div>-->
  </div>
</section>
```